# FindControls<T> Extension Method - What am I missing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, textbox, extension-methods

I am trying to add an extension method to allow me to easily get a List of various different control types on a web forms ASP.Net page. I have created a new static class and inserted the extension method:

```
public static class PageExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> FindControls<T>(this Page page, bool recurse) where T : Control
    {
        List<T> found = new List<T>();
        Action<Control> search = null;
        search = ctrl =>
        {
            foreach (Control child in ctrl.Controls)
            {
                if (typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(child.GetType()))
                {
                    found.Add((T)child);
                }
                if (recurse)
                {
                    search(child);
                }
            }
        };
        search(control);
        return found;
    }
}
```

Now I want to call the method from my page, so I added this:

```
    protected void ResetControls()
    {
        var listTextBox = this.Page.FindControls<TextBox>(true);
    }
```

However I get the compile error:

'System.Web.UI.Page' does not contain a definition for 'FindControls' and no extension method 'FindControls' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.Page' could be found

I am using Master Pages if that makes any difference, but what am I missing here?

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you are missing a reference and/or a using statement in the code where your ResetControls() method is.

Comment: Does your namespace for Extension method and Page matches ? otherwise include `using` for namespace containing extension method.